# Excel .xlam add-in causes error on startup [error -2147417848]

Tags: .net, excel, vba, startup, add-in

I recently wrote a VBA module to d/l stock price data into an Excel (2016 desktop) program. It works but causes an error on add-in startup of the Excel program. It appears to be trying to load some .Net facilities (which it never did before this module) and fails at that point with error message -2147417848. After clicking OK, the code will run, but each time all instances of Excel are closed, opening Excel again shows error.

I captured the code below by using a Power Query and macro recorder. I would be happy to start fresh with code from another working implementation that uses either CSV or JSON.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions you can provide.

```
Sub avGetQuotes(symbol As String, history As Boolean)
'
' Fetch historical and current quotes from Alpha Vantage
'
Dim size As String
Dim qt As WorkbookQuery
Dim apiKeyNow As String

apiKeyNow = [MY API KEY]
If history Then
    size = "full" 'all data
Else
    size = "compact" '100 days
End If
'clear any previous query data
activeSheet.Range("A:G").EntireColumn.Clear
For Each qt In ActiveWorkbook.Queries
   qt.Delete
Next qt
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="query1", _
    Formula:="let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
" Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(""http://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED" _
    & "&symbol=" & symbol & "&outputsize=" & size & "&apikey=" & apiKeyNow & """))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) _
    & " #""Time Series (Daily)"" = Source[#""Time Series (Daily)""]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) _
    & " #""Converted to Table"" = Record.ToTable(#""Time Series (Daily)"")," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) _
    & " #""Expanded Value"" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#" & """Converted to Table"", ""Value"", " _
    & "{""1. open"", ""2. high"", ""3. low"", ""4. close"", ""5. adjusted close""}," _
    & "{""Open"", ""High"", ""Low"", ""Close"", ""Adjusted close""})" _
    & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & " #""Expanded Value"""
''Uncomment to run query on new sheet
'Sheets.Add After:=activeSheet
With activeSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""query1"";Extended Properties="""""), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [query1]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "query1"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
'Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
With activeSheet
    .Range("A1:F1").AutoFilter
    .Range("A1") = "Date" 'change from "Name"
    .Range("F1:F501") = .Range("F1:F501").value 'Force first 500 adjusted prices from text to values
    With .UsedRange.columns("A").Cells
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlYMDFormat)
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display
    End With
End With
'clean up Power Query
ActiveWorkbook.Queries("query1").Delete
Do While ActiveWorkbook.Connections.count > 0
   ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(ActiveWorkbook.Connections.count).Delete
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't get anywhere until you get the error code right.  It is *minus* 2147417848.  Google the hex version to get good hits, 0x80010106.  Nothing you could ever do with VBA code, even in .NET it is quite a stretch.  Otherwise a typical "trader" problem.  Use telephone/email to get everybody involved with this to help you.

Comment: Hans - Thank you for the reply and correction. I did a search on the hex code you provided but it appears this code has a multitude of potential causes, but I could not find anything related to VBA, .Net or Excel add-ins. You wrote, "Nothing you could ever do with VBA code, even in .NET it is quite a stretch." Could you please clarify? Do you mean that it is unlikely this error is caused by an error in VBA code or a problem loading a .Net facility?